# List distinct on tuple properties

Tags: c#, list, tuples, distinct

I have a list of Tuples that looks like this:

`List<Tuple<double, double, double, string, string, string>> myList;`

The double values represent X-Y-Z cooridinate values, and the strings are certain properties that are attached to these coordinates.

Now i want to use the `myList.lis.Distinct().ToList()` method to filter out any duplicates. After all, 1 coordinate can be the start of a line, while another is the endpoint of another line, but as they are connected i get the point XYZ point twice in my list, but with other string properties.
But i only want to use the Distinct on the 3 double values of the Tuple and ignore the strings.

So far i haven't figured out yet how to do so. Is this possible, and how so ?

Comment: not sure why you are using tuples here, with 6 properties, you definitely need a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create new class and override `Equals` method to use coordinates only:

```
class Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Point);
    }

    protected bool Equals(Point other)
    {
        return X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y) && Z.Equals(other.Z);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = X.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Y.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Z.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really usefull. I assume i can also add an if statement for the property within the Equals check? so if 2 coordinates are the same, and the property different, i always want to keep the one "ArcStart" and not the "LineEnd" ?

Comment: @Dante1986 yes, you can define `Equals` method as you want

Answer (score 10):

You can use `GroupBy` linq method like this:

```
var result = myList.GroupBy(x => new {x.Item1, x.Item2, x.Item3})
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```

Demo is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vrebws)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [DistinctBy](https://morelinq.github.io/2.8/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_DistinctBy__2.htm) method in [MoreLINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) library.

```
points.DistinctBy(c => new {c.Item1, c.Item2, c.Item3}).ToList();
```